# JSON "has" method in a For loop creating DOM elements

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, dom

I'm making a Lightbox based on a JSON file. So I've got a loop to identify objects in the JSON file that have a chosen ID, and then make as much slides as there are linked photos in the JSON file.

Some of the elements I need to display are under `"image": xxx.jpg`  but for other elements the object doesn't have image as a nameValue but `"video": xxxx.mp4`  instead, so i'm trying to use the `has` method.

My problem is that the console throws " `media[i]` is not a function. My idea is to check if the i in media has image or video ValueName, and depending on which it has create the adapted DOM element.

The loop works fine with other DOM creating elements where I don't need to use `has` and I've frequently used `media[i].image` and similar  e.g:`` `media[i].name  or price etc `` with succes, but it is the first time i'm using the `has` method.

Thanks guys

```js
 const PhotographeID= 82; 

var jsonFile =  {
  "media": [
    {
      "photographerId": 82,
      "image": "Fashion_Yellow_Beach.jpg"
    },
    {
      "photographerId": 82,
      "image": "Event-_eddingGazebo.jpg"
    },
    {
      "photographerId": 82,
      "video": "Event_18thAnniversary.mp4"
    },
    {
      "photographerId": 82,
      "video": "Art_Wooden_Horse_Sculpture.mp4"
    }
  ]
}

const lightbox  = document.getElementById('Lightbox-content');

function findMediaId(jsonFile, idToLookFor) {
  var media = jsonFile.media;
  for (var i = 0; i < media.length; i++) {
    if (media[i].photographerId == idToLookFor) {
            
     // Creating Dom Elements 

     const mySlides=  document.createElement('div');
     mySlides.classList.add('mySlides');
     mySlides.setAttribute("display", "none");
     lightbox.appendChild(mySlides);

     if ( media[i].has('image')) {
       const lightBoxImage =  document.createElement('img');
       lightBoxImage.src = "../FishEye_Photos\\Sample Photos\\" + media[i].photographerId + "\\" + media[i].image; 
       lightBoxImage.classList.add('lightBoxImage');
       mySlides.appendChild(lightBoxImage);
     }
     else if ( media[i].has('video'))  {
       const lightBoxVideo =  document.createElement('video');
       lightBoxVideo.src = "../FishEye_Photos\\Sample Photos\\" + media[i].photographerId + "\\" + media[i].video; 
       lightBoxVideo.classList.add('lightBoxVideo');
       mySlides.appendChild(lightBoxVideo);
     } 

     const slideText = document.createElement('p');
     slideText.classList.add('slideText');
     if ( media[i].has('image')) {
       slideText.textContent = media[i].image.split('.')[0].split('_').slice(1).join(' ');
     } 
     else if ( media[i].has('video'))  {
       slideText.textContent = media[i].video.split('.')[0].split('_').slice(1).join(' ');
     } 
     mySlides.appendChild(slideText);
    }
  }
}
findMediaId(jsonFile, PhotographeID);
```

```html
<div id='Lightbox-content'>
  
</div>
```

Comment: What should `.has` be? `.hasOwnProperty()`? `.includes()`?

Comment: Firstly, JSON is a text format; it doesn't have "methods". Secondly, you have provided too much code, and too little information about your test input. Try to break the problem down to a [mcve].

Comment: The error message is quite clear. `has` is not a function. This is because there is no `has` method on DOM objects. `has()` is a method in JQuery. What is it you are thinking that `has` is supposed to do?

Comment: `.has()` is a method for Sets or Maps. Try [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) instead.

Comment: @Sean It's also a JQuery method for finding descendants. The OP might mean that but we need more info.

Comment: @ScottMarcus There's no jQuery in the code or question or tags. And `media[i]` isn't a DOM object.

Comment: @Sean Yes, I know, but it's possible the OP is trying to use some JQuery they saw somewhere. We need more info. before we can say for sure what the solution is.

Comment: @pilchard Yes, I do, but since you yourself indicate that you are guessing, I'm simply saying, let's get more info. from the OP before stating what the solution is.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I don't think the comments not mentioning you are directed at you—they're directed at the OP.

Comment: I thought it was used to search if a Json object had a property or not. Sorry for the long code, i'll keep in mind to make it even shorter next time. 
@Sean your method worked fine, if you could set it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I guess I'll have to study the Has method again, and mabye be more careful that it's not JQUERY. I think I sill confuse Maps too much

Comment: @Sean I’ve been a member of SO for about 10 years, I know how comments work. You directed a comment to me and I replied to you. Pilchard did the same and I replied to him.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you started both conversation threads by replying to comments directed at the OP as though they were directed at you.

Comment: @Sean *as though they were directed at you* No, I didn't. I direct my comment to you because I wanted you to know something related to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.has()` is a method for Sets or Maps. Try [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) instead:

> The **`hasOwnProperty()`** method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it).

— Mozilla JavaScript Reference